# Using AWS Lambda to delete a Cognito User

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I want to give user's the ability to delete their account in my android app. I already set up a login/sig up functionality with AWS Amplify and a `AWS Cognito User Pool`. But Amplify doesn't provide a "delete User" functionality, so I wanted to use a lambda function to delete a user from my cognito user pool.

The function will be called when the user clicks on "delete my account" in the app. To test the function, I use a hard coded username in the Lambda function, instead of passing one into the function. But even that doesn't work. After deploying the Lambda function, I run the function by clicking on "Test" in the console. The console then shows `Execution result: succeeded` but the response is `null`. I would either epect a Status 200 or 400 as response. And in the CloudWatch logs of the Execution I can only see my first log statement ("I was here"), the other two don't show up. And in the Cognito Console the user is still there.

This is my `Lambda Code` (`Node.js`):

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

console.log("I was here");

var params = {
 UserPoolId: 'syz****f-dev', 
 Username: '5b53****138'
};
var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
    "region": 'eu-central-1',
});

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminDeleteUser(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) { 
      var response = {
        statusCode: 400,
        body: JSON.stringify('Didnt work!'),
      };
      console.log(err, err.stack); 
      return response;
    }
    else  {
      response = {
        statusCode: 200, 
        body: JSON.stringify('yeah!'),
      };
      console.log(data);          
      return response;
    }
  }); 
};
```

The user "5b53....138" is still there in my Cognito User Pool "syz....f-dev" after I test this function:

[image]

This is the log file that I found in Cloudwatch:

[image]

My Lambda Function has a role with these 3 policies and I used the IAM Policy Simulator and the action `AdminDeleteUser` is allowed with `AmazonCognitoAuthenticatedIdentities`, so this shouldn`t be the problem:

- AmazonCognitoAuthenticatedIdentities
- AmazonCognitoPowerUser
- AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole

In CloudWatch I can see that the function got invoked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, your user pool id is wrong, find the correct on by opening your Cognito user pool: The first thing you see when opening your user pool in the console is the id:

[image]

It starts with your region followed by a _, in your case `eu-central-1_`.

Then try using this code instead of your adminDeleteUser function. Then it should work:

```
try {
  const data = await cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminDeleteUser(params).promise();
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But Amplify doesn't provide a "delete User" functionality, so I wanted to use a lambda function to delete a user from my cognito user pool.

It looks like you can now do this directly with `Auth`.  Here are a few examples and sources:

Typescript (JS):

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

export async function deleteUser() {
  try {
    const result = await Auth.deleteUser();
    console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error deleting user', error);
  }
}
```

SOURCE: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/delete_user/q/platform/js/

Java (Android):

```
Amplify.Auth.deleteUser(
    () -> Log.i("AuthQuickStart", "Delete user succeeded"),
    error -> Log.e("AuthQuickStart", "Delete user failed with error " + error.toString())
);
```

SOURCE: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/delete_user/q/platform/android/